# Multiple Conditions in Where Clause, breaking with second condition

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

This is a very simple issue.  I must just be doing something stupid:

This query echos out a row id number:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userpage WHERE uploaderrating = $rating";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row1= mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo $row1[id];
```

When I add in an additional condition (even though the condition is DEFINITELY met in the SQL database the the echo does produce anything (i.e. the variable is empty).  The failing code is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userpage WHERE uploaderrating = $rating and reviewer = NULL";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row1= mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo $row1[id];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use

```
reviewer = NULL
```

You need to use

```
reviewer IS NULL
```

NULL is an undefined value, so it isn't equal to anything; so you need to use IS to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM userpage WHERE uploaderrating = $rating and reviewer IS NULL";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row1= mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row1[id];
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know null values are verified with IS

- ... where xxx IS null
- ... where xxx IS NOT null